# Does AVPlayer support live event rewind?

Tags: ios, avplayer, http-live-streaming, rewind

I'm using AVPlayer to play streamed content. AFAIK, there are 3 kinds of stream contents

1. Progressive download: like VOD, this is a complete video. I can rewind & forward and get the duration of the video
2. Live streaming: this is like watching a TV channel. I can't get the duration
3. Live event: like a football match

Correct me if I'm wrong.

My question is Can AVPlayer work with live event? For example, the football match starts at 7:00AM and is about to last for 2 hours. You open the stream at 8:00AM, can you rewind back? Does the AVPlayer update the duration continuously ?

Also, I found the `currentPlaybackTime`

> For video-on-demand or progressively downloaded content, this value is
>   measured in seconds from the beginning of the current item. Changing
>   the value of this property moves the playhead to the new location. For
>   content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time
>   from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.

Not sure what `For content streamed live from a server, this value represents the time from the beginning of the playlist when it was first loaded.` mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find this document to be useful [Technical Note TN2288 Example Playlist Files for use with HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2288/_index.html)

**Basic Video on Demand (VOD) Playlist**

> The index file is static and contains a complete list of URLs to all
>   media files created since the beginning of the presentation. This kind
>   of session allows the client full access to the entire program

**Live Playlist (Sliding Window)**

> For live sessions, the index file is updated by removing media URIs
>   from the file as new media files are created and made available.

**Event Playlist**

> However, with the EVENT tag, you cannot change the playlist at all;
>   you may only append new segments to the end of the file. They cannot
>   be added at the front. New segments are added until the event has
>   concluded, at which time the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag is appended

So technically, I think iOS AVPlayer can handle live event rewind, it only depends on how the server generates the playlist file